# return array value from object into array

Tags: javascript

I have some object
After using JSON.stringify(data) it returns me next json:

```
[{"id":77,"image":{"id":266, "zoom_url":"https://img.jpg"},"name": "example name"}]
```

if i start filter my object, adding JSON.stringify(data, ['id','image']) it returns me next JSON, without `zoom_url`

```
[{"id":77,"image":{"id":266}}]
```

in perfect case i need return after all next JSON view:

```
[{"id":77,"image":"https://img.jpg"}]
```

How can i do this manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with arguments to `JSON.stringify()`, because all it can do is filter, it can't transform the structure. So it can't replace the object value of the `image` object with just its `zoom_url` string.

Do it with array and object operations.

```js
let data = [{"id":77,"image":{"id":266, "zoom_url":"https://img.jpg"},"name": "example name"}];
let new_data = data.map(({id, image}) => ({id, image: image.zoom_url}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(new_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `JSON.stringify`, you can convert the `data` into the format you want.

```
let newData = data.map(obj => {
    return {
        id: obj.id,
        image: obj.image.zoom_url
    };
});

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use JSON.parse the string into the array. Use array.map t then transform the object into the format you want.

```js
const str = '[{"id":77,"image":{"id":266, "zoom_url":"https://img.jpg"},"name": "example name"}]';
const data = JSON.parse(str);
const result = data.map(({ id, image: { zoom_url } }) => ({id, image: zoom_url}));
console.log(result);
```

Without all the destructuring

```js
const str = '[{"id":77,"image":{"id":266, "zoom_url":"https://img.jpg"},"name": "example name"}]';
const data = JSON.parse(str);
const result = data.map(function(item) {
  const id = item.id;
  const zoom_url = item.image.zoom_url;
  return { id: id, image: zoom_url };
});
console.log(result);
```